# Magento 2 - Using KOJS template for filter component?

Tags: javascript, template, uicomponent, knockoutjs, magento2.1.5

On the same page I have several custom product grids with above them a filter toolbar.

To simplify the case :

```
<?php foreach ($grids as $id => $grid): ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="item-<?php echo $id; ?>"
             class="item"
             data-bind="scope:'filter'"
        >
            <div class="filter-container">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                {
                    "#item-<?php echo $id; ?>": {
                        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                           "components": {
                                "filter": {
                                    "component": "Foo_Bar/js/filter",
                                    "template": "Foo_bar/filter",
                                    "config": {
                                        "currentElement": "#item-<?php echo $id; ?>"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                </script>
            </div>
            <ul class="products-list">
               <li class="product">Product 1</li>
               <li class="product">Product 1</li>
               <li class="product">Product 1</li>
               <li class="product">Product 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My `JS Component` file :

```
# \Foo\Bar\view\frontend\web\js\filter.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Foo_Bar/filter'
        },
        options: {
            option1: 'option1',
            option2: 'option2'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.applyFilters();
            this.getTrigger().on('click', $.proxy(this.triggerFilter, this))
        },
        triggerFilter: function (event) {
            this.applyFilters();
        },
        applyFilters: function () {
            // logic
        },
        getCurrentElement: function () {
            return $(this.currentElement);
        }
    });
});
```

With that I would like that my filter component is linked to the `<div id="item-<?php echo $id; ?>">` element that I can work with the `<ul class="products-list">` element.

My questions are :

- Is `JS Component` + `KOJS template` the best way / practice to perform that?
- Do I have to simply use `Magento block` + `Magento template` + `RequireJS plugin`?
- Is there a simple way to retrieve the current targeted element in `UiComponent` without using `config` node as in my example for the `KOJS` way?